# Cannot find declaration in C++ code after upgrade to NDK 14

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android-studio-2.3

I updated my Android Studio 2.3 to use NDK 14. Everything works as expected when you use the code (code compiles and the app is running as expected). However, for some reason, when you try to jump to the deceleration of any C++ object/function/variable you get a message that studio (regardless of the code):

> Cannot find declaration to go to

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image: Screen shot]

**Edit:** I just downgraded back to NDK 13b and the problem was solved. This is a workaround, but without a fix I would not recommend to upgrade yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Android Studio 2.4 Preview 3 using externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild with:

- gradle 2.14.1
- gradle plugin 2.2.3
- NDK r14b (14.1.3816874)

Comment: I have the same problem. Code naviation of C++ in Android Studio is not working for me. Android Studio: 3.1.4, NDK: r14b, gradle 3.0.1. Is it my setup or is it a general Android Studio issue?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the cause or fix yet, but the bug for this is here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231382