# Android Studio- C, C++ source file navigation

Tags: android, android-studio

I have *JNI* code in my android project. Android Studio cannot parse the C, C++ files in the *JNI* code and hence functions like jump to declaration, jump to definition etc are not working. Is this a limitation of Android Studio? Is there any way I can have native source file navigation in Android Studio?
Please note, it's an already running project and all the native calls are hooked to java classes through *JNI* calls. I just want Android Studio to parse the native files so that I can use navigation utilities like *Jump to declaration* etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, import external library to NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011869/android-import-external-library-to-ndk)

Comment: what is ur gradle, gradle plugin & ndk ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584272/cannot-find-declaration-in-c-code-after-upgrade-to-ndk-14

Comment: Gardle is 4.1 and ndk is r1e.How to find out the gradle plugin version ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Code naviation of C++ in Android Studio is not working for me. Android Studio: 3.1.4, NDK: r14b, gradle 3.0.1. Is it my setup or is it a general Android Studio issue?